# Using two optimizers with keras functional API - Will it work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to build a system with the following structure:

```
input = Input()
embedding = Embedding()(input)
lstm_1 = LSTM()(embedding)
out_1 = Dense()(lstm_1)
lstm_2 = LSTM()(embedding)
x = concatenate([lstm_1, lstm_2])
out_2 = Dense()(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[out_1, out_2])

optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'out_1': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'out_2': 'binary_crossentropy'}, metrics=['acc'])
```

So I have a shared `input` for `lstm_1` and `lstm_2`. `lstm_1` is put into an output layer and concatenated with `lstm_2`. The concatenation is put into another output layer. Now I want to fit this model with a prediction for `out_1` and `out_2`. Will they learn in the same time so that the learning of `out1` effects the `lstm_1` in a way that it changes to optimize `out_2`?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: The title is misleading, there is only a single optimizer here.